# Filter all entities based on common property in DynamicData application

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dynamic-data

I have dynamic data site based on EF CodeFirst context (using [DynamicData.EFCodeFirstProvider library](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/using-dynamic-data-with-ef-code-first.html)). Everything works, but all my entities inherit from one "common" entity that has (among others) a `"IsDeleted"` property. I want to filter items in dynamic data site based on this property (show only ones where `IsDeleted == false`). I have tried setting Where parameter of asp:EntityDataSource to item.IsDeleted, item.IsDeleted == false, item.IsDeleted = 0 and IsDeleted == false, but all I get is exception like this:

'item.IsDeleted' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly.

As I figured out, this "Where" property accepts sql filter, and I don't know how to pass this argument. Resources I found online all use this property in combination with strongly typed asp:EntityDataSource and I'm wondering how to filter this thata and if this is the right place to do it.

Comment: This should probably be closed as Dynamic Data has been merged into other projects like EF Code First and MVC, and the answer to how to do this in those updated libraries differs.

Comment: I agree. I will close it now. The project where I needed this is long time over also :)

Comment: Happy to help (got here via your twitter activity on the right of http://blog.goranobradovic.com/2011/09/solution-for-vhd_boot_host_volume_not_enough_space-error-in-windows-8/ !)